# How to convert multi-byte UTF-8 character representation to one byte while retaining (non)alphanumeric property?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 string as a `char*`. In order to get the *one byte per character* property (and thus have random access into the string by character indexes) I currently just remove all UTF-8 continuation bytes from it (I would like to avoid "proper" conversion to a static byte width representation).

Instead of removing all continuation bytes I would like to be able to check whether a given multi-byte UTF-8 character is alphanumeric (or not) and then replace it with a corresponding ASCII character (let's say `a` for alphanumerics and `.` otherwise). How do I do this?

Comment: What is the alphabet in current string?. Can it have some Japanese or Chinese or some other characters from Asia ??

Comment: @Zimbabao: could be anything (i.e. the alphabet is the whole of Unicode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each byte in the string:

- If it is an ASCII byte, just copy it.
- If it is a UTF-8 head byte, decode starting from that byte to `wchar_t` using `mbrtowc`, determine an ASCII character whose classification matches by comparing the results of the `isw*()` functions, and copy that ASCII character to the output.
- If it is anything else, skip it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in general, as letters outside the ASCII range (such as α) may be accented as well (ἄ). But you can apply the [NFD Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) to decompose accented codepoints into their constituents, then check whether the components lie within the ASCII range. ICU has [normalization support](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/normalization).

Answer (score 0):

Unicode got total 1114111 (0x10FFFF) as highest code points, that means almost over a million characters. Single byte can represent 256 characters.

So simple answer is you can't do it, that way.

As far I understand from question, you want this for random access to characters in the string. You use 32bit characters. (Correct me If I am wrong).

Rather then handling it by writing your code use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), and using converter [convert it into UTF-32](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/convexp?conv=UTF-32&s=ALL) (4 byte character). [ucnv_convertEx](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#af4c967c5afa207d064c24e19256586b6) is the function to be used for this.

Comment: I don't want to convert to a fixed width encoding, and I don't mind replacing multi-byte UTF-8 character representations with ASCII characters that don't really correspond to them, as long as the replacement character's "alphanumeric" property corresponds to the replaced character's. So e.g. `ë` could be replaced with `a`.

Comment: And this you want even for other languages? . eg Asian languages